# Inheriting from two classes with Java?

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

I have made a class to include a custom title bar with my apps logo on it. This works well except that for the majority of my classes I need to be able to inherit that functionality as well as that of say a ListActivity. What to do?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Tagging android doesn't specify what language you are coding in, but I assume java in which multiple inheritance is impossible.  You would need to alter your design.

Comment: Use composition instead of inheritance. Java does not allow multiple inheritance of state.

Comment: And even if it did, you'd probably still want to use composition.

Comment: if you want to inheriting two class in single class then create your classes  using C++, use JNI and NDK for access these class behavior or properties inside java code.because java does not allow multiple inheritance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should favor composition (and delegation) over inheritance :

```
   public interface FirstClassInterface {
       void method1();
   }

   public interface SecondClassInterface {
       void method2();
   }

   public class FirstClass implements FirstClassInterface {
       // ...
   }

   public class SecondClass implements SecondClassInterface  {
       // ...
   }

   public class FirstAndSecondClass implements FirstClassInterface , SecondClassInterface       
    {
       private FirstClassInterface firstclass;
       private SecondClassInterface secondclass;

       public FirstAndSecondClass(FirstClassInterface firstclassinterface, SecondClassInterface   secondclassinterface) {
           this.firstclass= firstclassinterface;
           this.secondclass= secondclassinterface;
       }

       public void method1() {
           this.firstclass.method1();
       }

       public void method2() {
           this.secondclass.method2();
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           FirstAndSecondClass t = new FirstAndSecondClass(new FirstClass(), new SecondClass());
           t.method1();
           t.method2();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you **cannot** have:

```
class MyClass extends ClassA, ClassB { ... }
```

Depending on what you are doing, it might be possible to use:

```
class ClassB extends ClassA { ... }

class MyClass extends ClassB { ... }
```

Comment: can we do this using NDK & C++ without using interface?